# node C:\Users\XXXXXXXX\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\sails\bin\sails.js module.js:473 throw err;

Tags: selenium, npm, sails.js, sails-mongo, selenium-extent-report

After I npm installed Sails.js on Windows 10, "sails" command is not recognized.

Can someone give me a hint on what values to use in the PATH variable? As I understand it is Node.exe that runs the sails.js file. But if I try tunning "node sails.js" command in cmd, it recognizes it, but can't find some of the dependencies.

On my Windows 7 machine everything installed and is running like a charm

Comment: I don't think `node sails.js` is the intended use. You either use `sails lift` or `node app.js` (I believe that command is what `sails lift` uses under the hood)

Comment: i m following this steps where sails lift is important to use after node app.......MongoDB & NodeJS on same host
Download and install NodeJS
Download and install MongoDB
Run Mongo daemon
Open Console
Navigate to MongoDB folder
Run mongod
Download ExtentX, unzip, navigate to its folder and run:
npm install
sails lift
Open browser and navigate to the NodeJS server URL + port. Ex: localhost:1337,..........................................for more info http://extentreports.com/docs/extentx/

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how you installed sails, but as I do not have enough reputation to post a comment I am writing this as an answer.

So did you install sails globally?
Which command you used while installing sails

```
npm -g install sails
```

OR

```
npm install sails
```

You should use

```
npm -g install sails
```

**Edit**

Could you follow the below steps in command prompt with administrator rights.

```
npm cache clear

Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Scope CurrentUser -Force
npm install -g npm-windows-upgrade
npm-windows-upgrade

npm -g install sails
```

Let me know if you still face the issue.

Comment: it works successfully but after then when i go and fire command "sails lift"............................it throws error  like this....
C:\Users\XXXXXXXX\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\sails\bin\sails.js
module.js:473
      throw err;
      ^

Comment: no I mean which one of the 2 I mentioned did you use? Both are going to show you a success message but which one did you exactly use?

Comment: if i used  npm install sails ............it throws error like .......
C:\Users\Kunal\Downloads\extentx-community-1.0.2>npm install sails
npm WARN deprecated native-or-bluebird@1.1.2: 'native-or-bluebird' is deprecated. Please use 'any-promise' instead.
npm WARN mongodb-core@1.2.31 requires a peer of kerberos@~0.0 but none was installed.

Comment: I see some version issues could you check the edit I provided in my answer and see if that works?

Comment: only npm install -g npm-windows-upgrade this command is working and all others are throwing issue. and at the end of all commands it throws issues.

Comment: Okay no worries, now would you try npm -g install sails I think your version was having some issues this must be fixed now as you said upgrade command worked

Comment: Also if something throws error please mention those errors

Comment: i have fire the command it displays same errors.....................C:\Users\Kunal\Downloads\extentx-community-1.0.2>node C:\Users\XXXXXXXX\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\sails\bin\sails.js
module.js:473
      throw err;
      ^

Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\XXXXXXXX\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\sails\bin\sails.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:527:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:453:25)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:665:10)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:201:16)
    at bootstrap_node.js:626:3

Comment: C:\Users\XXXXXX\AppData\Roaming\npm can you put this as your PATH variable ?